# SQLite keep expanding

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I'm new to the blackberry development and to this site. right now, i'm working on an app that retrieve data from a json service. In my app I should parse the data into a database and save it in four tables. I already parsed the data and I was successful able to create the database and add the first and the second tables.

The problem that I'm facing right now is, the second table in my data base keep expanding. I checked the database in the sql browser and I discovered that everytime I click on the app icon it adds the 700 rows to the table again.(ex. 700 becomes 1400) .

(only to the second table, the first table works so fine).

Thank you in advance

This is my code:

```
public void parseJSONResponceInBB(String jsonInStrFormat)
{
    try {
        JSONObject json = newJSONObject(jsonInStrFormat);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("tables");

        for (inti = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            //Iterate through json array
            JSONObject j = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (j.has("Managers")) {
                add(new LabelField("Managers has been added to the database"));

                JSONArray j2 = j.getJSONArray("Managers");

                for (intk = 0; k < j2.length(); ++k) {
                    JSONObject MangersDetails = j2.getJSONObject(k);
                    if (MangersDetails.has("fName")) {
                        try {
                            URI myURI =
                                URI.create
                                ("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLite_Guide/"
                                 + "MyTestDatabase.db");

                            d = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(myURI);

                            Statement st =
                                d.createStatement
                                ("CREATE TABLE Managers ( "
                                 + "fName TEXT, " +
                                 "lName TEXT, " + "ID TEXT," + "Type TEXT )");

                            st.prepare();
                            st.execute();
                            st.close();
                            d.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            URI myURI =
                                URI.create
                                ("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLite_Guide/"
                                 + "MyTestDatabase.db");

                            d = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);

                            Statement st =
                                d.createStatement
                                ("INSERT INTO Managers(fName, lName, ID, Type) "
                                 + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

                            st.prepare();

                            for (intx = 0; x < j2.length(); x++) {
                                JSONObject F = j2.getJSONObject(x);
                                //add(new LabelField ("f"));
                                st.bind(1, F.getString("fName"));
                                st.bind(2, F.getString("lName"));
                                st.bind(3, F.getString("ID"));
                                st.bind(4, F.getString("Type"));
                                st.execute();
                                st.reset();
                            }
                            d.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    //Owners method
public voidparseJSONResponceInBB1(String jsonInStrFormat)
{
    try {
        JSONObject json = newJSONObject(jsonInStrFormat);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("tables");

        for (inti = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            //Iterate through json array
            JSONObject j = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (j.has("Owners")) {
                add(new LabelField("Owners has been added to the database"));
                JSONArray j2 = j.getJSONArray("Owners");
                for (intk = 0; k < j2.length(); ++k) {
                    JSONObject OwnersDetails = j2.getJSONObject(k);
                    if (OwnersDetails.has("fName")) {
                        try {
                            Statement st =
                                d.createStatement
                                ("CREATE TABLE Owners ( "
                                 + "fName TEXT, " +
                                 "lName TEXT, " + "ID TEXT," + "Type TEXT )");
                            st.prepare();
                            st.execute();
                            st.close();
                            d.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            Statement st =
                                d.createStatement
                                ("INSERT INTO Owners(fName, lName, ID, Type) "
                                 + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

                            st.prepare();
                            for (intx = 0; x < j2.length(); x++) {
                                JSONObject F = j2.getJSONObject(x);
                                //add(new LabelField ("f"));
                                st.bind(1, F.getString("fName"));
                                st.bind(2, F.getString("lName"));
                                st.bind(3, F.getString("ID"));
                                st.bind(4, F.getString("Type"));
                                st.execute();
                                st.reset();
                            }
                            d.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: These two functions just look like they will, without fail, add all the information from the JSON source every single time they are called. How are you calling them? how are you preventing them from being run twice? Should the functions themselves refuse to re-add content? Or should the functions only be called if the databases are not there? This might be easier to read if you split these apart into functions that create the tables, functions that populate the tables, and a function that creates a database handle. Aim for fifteen lines of code per function or less...

Comment: Sarnold, thank you for the quick response. I will work on that. I will split the code into methods. But, I'm asking the same question, how can I prevent the method or the code from running twice.

Comment: Thank you so much Sarnold. I tried the code that you put for me. I called the two methods in the constructor and now the database is not even showing.

Comment: Hrm; can you run your code in a debugger that allows you to step line-by-line through your code? That might be the easiest next step.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your goals are here.  If you want to replace the data in the database each time the json query runs, you should add a sqlite command to remove all the existing rows with the newly fetched ones coming in via JSON.

If you just want to keep certain types of records unique, you should add an index to the sqlite table.  The 'ID' column is a likely candidate for this.  You'll have to do some experiments to make sure a conflict is handled correctly - it may abort the entire transaction.  "INSERT OR REPLACE" is useful in that situation.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Actually, in my app I need to save the json in the database at the first time I open the app. After that, I will need to put a code that refresh the database manually. The user should be able to select a specific table and click refresh to update that table. right now, i'm working on dividing the code into smaller methods, I hope that would help a little. Btw, I tried to vote up for your answer but i'm still new so I can't sorry. I will in the future :).